# Hg root not known error in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am  using eclipse helios 3.2 for the development purpose also i am using Mercurial 3.2,Tortoise HG for configuration management but when i want to pull the repositories from bitbucket it shows the error that hg root not known.And also when i synchronise my changes then it shows the error that Authrization Failed 
   I am pulling the request by right clicking on project and selecting the Team option then selecting pull suboption but it shows the error that  hg root is not known
please let me know why this issue arising

Thanks
Umesh

Comment: Can you show the error?  Have you cloned before you've pulled?

Comment: Yes I have cloned before i have pulled